# Textarea like the one here in stackoverflow

Tags: javascript

I have a website that allows it's members to make posts. To make the post, they have to enter their text in a box similar to this one. However, I would like for them to be able to edit the content with html tags (but not abuse this privilege by changing the background color or something using pure html). In addition, I would also like for them to be able to have Bold, Italics and other buttons on the top so that when they select the text and click on one of those, the text gets modified respectively. In essence, I am looking for a text-entering box pretty much like stackoverflow.

Is there an open-source solution? If not, could you guys lead me in the right direction as to how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is a tried-and-true solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been under the impression that [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is a great (if too bulky) text editor for the web.

### edit:

Well, it was bulky when I was using it 4 years ago.  2.2MB isn't too bad now.  I think it used to be 20+

Comment: It's no longer bulky, particularly if you remove all the documentation and things you don't need.

Comment: @Jordan, yes, I seem to remember that there were megabytes upon megabytes of documentation and variety that I always just wound up deleting :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of this page it looks like they are using [WMD](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/)

They have a few blog post about WMD on [stackoverflow's blog](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-6254779591266030%3awa6mxc6y8y6&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=wmd&sa=Search)